# Is Uglifier breaking my js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, uglifier

I'm using rails, uglifier and have just started using coffeescript. My coffee script for handling ajax completion is:

```
handleAjaxComplete = (xhr, response, status) ->
    myFeatherBox.close() if myFeatherBox?
    if $(xhr.target).hasClass "crud_create"
        #creation button hit
        myFeatherBox = $.featherlight response.responseText, afterOpen: ->
            $('form#frm_create').validate()
            $('#frm_create input[type!=hidden]').first().focus()
            return
    else #etc.
```

This becomes the following javascript:

```
handleAjaxComplete = function(xhr, response, status) {
  var new_aka_song_id;
  if (myFeatherBox != null) {
    myFeatherBox.close();
  }
  if ($(xhr.target).hasClass("crud_create")) {
    myFeatherBox = $.featherlight(response.responseText, {
      afterOpen: function() {
        $('form#frm_create').validate();
        $('#frm_create input[type!=hidden]').first().focus();
      }
    });
  } else //etc.
```

But then when I open the hosted page (it's on heroku), `myFeatherBox.close()` didn't seem to be running. I checked the uglified code and it seems to have become:

```
a=function(t,s) {
var o;
if(null!=h&&h.close(),$(t.target).hasClass("crud_create"))
    h=$.featherlight(s.responseText,{
        afterOpen:function(){
            $("form#frm_create").validate(),
            $("#frm_create input[type!=hidden]").first().focus()
        }
    });
else //etc.
```

(I've added some whitespace where I don't think it will matter to make it a little more readable).

My concern is with the condition on the third line of the uglified code. Am I correct that this is breaking what I'm trying to do? If so, how do I fix my coffee script so that the uglifier plays nice?

Comment: It's ugly but I don't see where it would break. To me it looks the same. What's your concern ?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error on that line in the console?

Comment: It doesn't break, as `!=` > `&&` > `,` by the rules of precedence.

Comment: No errors are occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a, b
```

in this context, is an expression whose value is the value of `b` (see [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)).
That's why the uglified test

```
if(null!=h&&h.close(),$(t.target).hasClass("crud_create"))
```

is the same as

```
null!=h && h.close();
if ($(t.target).hasClass("crud_create"))
```

which is equivalent, due to [the short-circuit behavior of `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation), to

```
if (null!=h) h.close();
if ($(t.target).hasClass("crud_create"))
```

So there doesn't seem to be any problem in this uglyfication.

Comment: Something's a little puzzling (but I didn't do any research) : why does uglify.js change `a;if(b)` to `if(a,b)` ? There doesn't seem to be any gain.

Comment: Isn't it because there are two consecutive conditions?

Comment: uglify.js could have kept `null!=h&&h.close();if ($(t.target).hasClass("crud_create"))`, there doesn't seem to be any gain in `if(null!=h&&h.close(),$(t.target).hasClass("crud_create"))` (it's the same number of characters). But I guess the algo isn't especially designed to choose the code looking the most like the original one.